# Not all jquery functions are working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I hope you can help me. I am not going to lie; I am quite new to ASP.Net. I am busy with a course; *Building a Web App with ASP.NET 5, MVC 6, EF7 and AngularJS* on Pluralsight, but have been unable to get a solution for my problem:

**My Problem:**
**It seems that jquery works for some functions, but not others. It woks for updating/changing the user name and the menu alert. The collapse does not work, nor does the function to change the color of the main block (this specific function worked for about 3 tests in Firefox, but never worked in Chrome).**

**Some detail of project:**

- I started an empty ASP.Net 5 project in VS 2015
- I have installed the packages needed via the bower.json method
  (below):

  {
     "name": "ASP.NET",
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": 
     "underscore": "~1.8.3",
     "jquery": "~2.1.4"
    }
  }

Here is my index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>The World</title>
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" /> </head> <body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <img src="img/SamHastings.jpg" alt="headshot" class="headshot" />
        <span id="username">Sam Hastings</span>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
            <div>
                <button id="sidebarToggle">Toggle Menu</button>
            </div>
            <h1>The World</h1>
            <p>This will be a fun website soon!</p>
            <form>
               <div>
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <input />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Location</label>
                    <input />
                </div>
                <div><input type="submit" value="Add" /></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            © 2015 The World Ltd.
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/site.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

And here is my site.js code:

```
  var ele = $("#username");
    ele.text("Corne le Roux");
    var main = $("#main");
    main.on("mouseenter", function () {
        main.style = "background-color: #888;";
    });

    main.on("mouseleave", function () {
        main.style = "";
    });

    var menuItems = $("ul.menu li a");
    menuItems.on("click", function () {
        var me = $(this);
        alert(me.text());
    });

    var sidebarAndWrapper = $("#sidebar,#wrapper");
    $("sidebarToggle").on("click", function () {
        sidebarAndWrapper.toggleClass("hide-sidebar");
        if (sidebarAndWrapper.hasClass("hide-sidebar")) {
            $(this).text("Show Sidebar");
        } else {
            $(this).text("Hide Sidebar");
        }   
    });    
})();
```

And here is my css:

```
#sidebar {
    background: #2a2c36;
    color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-transition: left ease .25s;
    -o-transition: left ease .25s;
    -webkit-transition: left ease .25s;
    transition: left ease .25s;
}
    #sidebar.hide-sidebar {
        left: -250px;
        -moz-transition: left ease .25s;
        -o-transition: left ease .25s;
        -webkit-transition: left ease .25s;
        transition: left ease .25s;
    }
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 0 0 250px;
    -moz-transition: margin-left ease .25s;
    -o-transition: margin-left ease .25s;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left ease .25s;
    transition: margin-left ease .25s;
}
    #wrapper.hide-sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
        -moz-transition: margin-left ease .25s;
        -o-transition: margin-left ease .25s;
        -webkit-transition: margin-left ease .25s;
        transition: margin-left ease .25s;
    }
```

I thank you in advance!

Comment: Your jQuery is incorrect. You cannot use style this way. jQuery uses methods, but not properties.

Comment: Also, do not use variables in handlers. Use this.

Comment: Hi Yeldar, thanks for the response. I AM new to ASP.Net (and some of the packages used). Can you perhaps give me more detail? In the course it works fine when Shawn Wildermuth presents and teaches it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i followed the same tutorial, I solved it like this:

```
 var main = $("#main");
main.on("mouseenter", function () {
    main.css("background-color", "#888");
});

main.on("mouseleave", function () {
    main.css("background-color", "");
});
```

Comment: thanks for the input, and sorry for the belated reply. I did some other courses in the interim, and only picked up this course again now. :) Your solution does not work for me unfortunately. However, this is only a small part of the course that is not used it would seem.